# Datatype for Dijkstra's algorithm?

Tags: types, dijkstra, smlnj

I'd like to turn a 2D array (having nodes but also obstacles) into a graph in order to run Dijkstra's algorithm in SML, but as a beginner I don't come up with a good idea about the datatype I should use.

Any help is welcome, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since we dont have much data structures in SML we can use list to represent the graph(This is one way to do that).
Represent the graph using adjacency list. List of list of list.

```
-val graph=[  [[3,5],[6,9]],
              [[4,7],[2,6]]    ];

val graph = [[[3,5],[6,9]],[[4,7],[2,6]]] : int list list list
```

Presume that the first element of the list is vertex '1', the second element of the  list is vertex '2' and so on.

In this example vertex 1 has 2 edges (3,6) with the distance of (5,9). And the same way vertex 2 has 2 edges (4,2) with the distance of (7,6) respectively.

Whenever a new edge comes in , add to the respective vertex list with the distance.